# Mutator and accessor for ArrayList

Tags: arraylist, accessor

Is it possible to provide mutator and accessor method for an ArrayList?
For example, an ArrayList of purchased item. There may have many items. How to have get and set method?
Thanks

Comment: Smells like homework. An extremely easy homework question at that.

Comment: Is this C# and .NET?  Add the appropriate tags to your question.

Comment: it`s BlueJ. There is arrayList of purchased item. Provide accessor and mutator method.

Comment: I need to put the get and set method inside the class shopping: 1) Class MusicalInstrument

public String getDescription() {
  return description;
 }

public void setDescription(String instrumentDescription) {
  description = instrumentDescription;
 }

Comment: 2) Class Shopping

public class Shopping
{
    private ArrayList<MusicalInstrument> purchased;
     
    public Shopping()
    {
        purchased = new ArrayList<MusicalInstrument>();
    }

GET Method:
public String getPurchased()
    {
        String Purchased = purchased.getDescription();
        return Purchased;
    }

=> “Cannot find symbol getDescription”

SET Method:
public void setPurchased(String instrumentPurchased)
    {
        purchased.setDescription(instrumentPurchased);
    }

=>“method SetDescription Java.lang.String”